# pass the spinner selected value to mysql using php from response in android

Tags: android

Hi In My Application I have two spinners class and section names displaying with date and one submit Button. After click the submit button the class name,section Name,date available in database or not.If Exist I want response from php.

I tested this code by using toast message it showing whatever I selected data displaying.

Can any one please help me how to resolve this issues.

**Attendance.class**

```
public class Attendance extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText fromDateEtxt;
    private DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = null;
    String line = null;
    int class_id;
    //String className = "";
    String sectionName = "";
    String[] class_name, section_name;
    Spinner classSpinner, sectionSpinner;
    private Map<String, Set<String>> classSectionMap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        // Spinner element
        classSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        sectionSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(AndroidSpinnerExampleActivity.this,
                          "Result : " +
                          "\nclassName : "+ String.valueOf(classSpinner.getSelectedItem()) +
                          "\nSectionName : "+ String.valueOf(sectionSpinner.getSelectedItem()), 

                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });

        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

        findViewsById();

        setDateTimeField();
        // Spinner click listener
        // spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Spinner Drop down elements
        final List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        final List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/getuser.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.e("Fail 1", "3");

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            Log.e("Fail 1", "4");

            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("Pass 1", "connection success ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }

        try {
            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json = null;

            class_name = new String[JA.length()];
            section_name = new String[JA.length()];

            String className = "";
            String sectionName = "";
            Set<String> sections;
            for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {

                json = JA.getJSONObject(i);
                // class_name[i] = json.getString("class_name");
                // section_name[i]=json.getString("section_name");
                className = json.getString("class_name");

                sectionName = json.getString("section_name");
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "classname"+sectionName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (classSectionMap.containsKey(className)) {
                    sections = classSectionMap.get(className);
                } else {
                    sections = new HashSet<String>();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "classname"+className, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                sections.add(sectionName);
                classSectionMap.put(className, sections);
            }
            Set<String> classKeys = classSectionMap.keySet();
            class_name = classKeys.toArray(new String[classKeys.size()]);
            Set<String> sectionkeys = classSectionMap.get(class_name[0]);
            if (sectionkeys != null) {
                section_name = sectionkeys.toArray(new String[sectionkeys
                        .size()]);
            }

            /*
             * for(int i=0;i<class_name.length;i++) { list1.add(class_name[i]);
             * list2.add(section_name[i]);
             * 
             * }
             */

            spinner_fn();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            // login.this.finish();

        }
    }

    private void spinner_fn() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                class_name);
        dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        classSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);



        classSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {

                Log.e("Position new", class_name[position]);
                Set<String> sectionkeys = classSectionMap
                        .get(class_name[position]);
                if (sectionkeys != null) {
                    section_name = sectionkeys.toArray(new String[sectionkeys
                            .size()]);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sectionName"+section_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        section_name);
                dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sectionSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

        });

        sectionSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // spinner.setSelection(position);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

    }

    private void findViewsById() {
        fromDateEtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt_fromdate);
        fromDateEtxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        fromDateEtxt.requestFocus();

        // toDateEtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt_todate);
        // toDateEtxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    }

    private void setDateTimeField() {
        fromDateEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);
        // toDateEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);

        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new OnDateSetListener() {

                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                        newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                        fromDateEtxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate
                                .getTime()));
                    }

                }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == fromDateEtxt) {
            fromDatePickerDialog.show();
        }

    }
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: `I tested this code by using toast message it showing whatever I selected data displaying.` Whats wrong with this code? What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: I have two spinners displaying data coming from server now if I click submit button I want to display student table if match the class_id and section_id

Comment: Better to do network operations  in AsyncTask. [check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: You got my point or not?

Comment: how to pass spinner selected values data from android to php and I want response

Comment: If you want to send data over network, You need to write an `API` Check out this [Tutoria](http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/the-simplest-way-to-post-parameters-between-android-and-php/) to understand how to write APIs.